# Swift Firebase: Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue at fileURL

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I have just recently updated to Swift 3.0 syntax and XCode 8.0.
I have had a bit of trouble with getting everything back in order after the update but one thing that I have not been able to fix is when writing data(particularly an image) to the database I am getting the following error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(setValue:) Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue at fileURL. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.'
```

This is my current writing process. Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

```
let roomRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

class Data {

    static let dataService = Data()

    fileprivate var _BASE_REF = roomRef
    fileprivate var _ROOM_REF_ = roomRef.child("rooms")

    fileprivate var _BASE_REF2 = roomRef
    fileprivate var _ROOM_REF_2 = roomRef.child("contents")

    var BASE_REF: FIRDatabaseReference {
        return _BASE_REF
    }

    var ROOM_REF: FIRDatabaseReference {
        return _ROOM_REF_
    }

    var storageRef: FIRStorageReference {
        return FIRStorage.storage().reference()
    }


    var fileURL: String!

    func createNewPost(_ user: FIRUser, title: String, author: String, date: String, story: String, data: Foundation.Data) {
        let filePath = "\(user.uid)/\(Int(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate))"
        let metaData = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
        storageRef.child(filePath).put(data, metadata: metaData) { (metaData, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error Uploading: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            //creating the URL 
            self.fileURL = metaData!.downloadURLs![0].absoluteString
            if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
                let idRoom = self.BASE_REF.child("rooms").childByAutoId()
                idRoom.setValue(["title": title, "author": author, "date": date, "story": story, "ThumbnailURLFromStorage": self.storageRef.child(metaData!.path!).description, "fileURL": self.fileURL])
            }
        }
    }

    func fetchData(_ callback: @escaping (Room) -> ()) {
    Data.dataService.ROOM_REF.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            let room = Room(key: snapshot.key, snapshot: snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
            callback(room)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to print the value of `self.fileURL` after initialization.

Comment: Can you show what `self.storageRef.child(metaData!.path!).description, ` `self.fileURL` prints out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of playing around I was able to figure this out. In the new Swift 3 Firebase wants you to be extremely specific as to what you are writing. Additionally, there can be no sort of optionals during this process.

Simply adding `String(self.fileURL)` to the end of the setValue function was enough to fix this problem. Hopefully this can help others! Please comment for further explanation.